# Is it possible to sort ImageVault on Filetype AND Filename?

Tags: episerver

I am sorting the images in my ImageVault with the following code:

```
//ImgListControl is of type:ImageStoreNET.Developer.WebControls.IVFileList
ImgListControl.SortBy = IVFileSortBy.FileName;
ImgListControl.SortDirection = IVSortDirection.Ascending;
```

However, I want to group on IVFileSortBy.FileExtension and then sort on FileName
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to abandon the usage of ImageVault:IVAlbumTree (if that's the control your are using?) and build something by your self. I'm fairly certain that it's easy to use LINQ .OrderBy(x => extension).ThenBy(x => name) to get the sorting you are after.

Comment: I am using : ImageStoreNET.Developer.WebControls.IVFileList

Comment: OK. Still pretty sure you need to skip the control and assemble something you can bind to a Repeater or build the markup by your self to get the sorting you're after.